# System.Management.ManagementClass Replacement Core Clr

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, coreclr

I have some code that resides in a asp.net application,
which uses System.Management.ManagementClass to query various
details about the hardware that is currently present.

We look at cpu, base board and bios details and use these for 
various things, i.e. identification

So now going cross plat with core clr & asp.net 5
we need to start porting our code.

The question then becomes how can this be achieved because the above mentioned class is not present (from my searching). To be more specific we are looking for a method that will now work cross platform is hardware based, and provides us with a way of generating a key based on the current hardware. So the only time this key would change, is if the hardware is replaced on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace `System.Management` will be probably never ported to .NET Core, especially not cross-plat. `System.Management` is a wrapper around WMI which again is a Windows library very much bound to the Windows platform. To my knowledge, .NET Core currently does not have any hardware based ids available.

How can it be achieved cross-platform: Build a NuGet package which host two implementations of the same contract. One basewd on net451 utilizing your existing WMI code and another one, which reads some serials using Linux methodologies. Do some research there. The /proc file system should have some but you could also P/Invoke into some linux libraries.

Comment: Yes you are correct. It requires .net framework to be installed

Comment: what's about Nuget Package https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/ ?

Comment: Well, world has changed in 4 years ;) ... I have not checked but it may that .NET Core 2+ / .NET 5 actually run this package ON WINDOWS. Not Linux.It has a dependency to Registry. I have not checked but if you do, tell us the result ;). However, overall, focus on PowerShell with your admin/config tasks. That is the future.